# Ms Access 2007 - Can sort or group report but not both, can't figure out why

Tags: sorting, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm stuck and confused and hopefully can get some help here. I have a query that pulls info from two tables and a report that reads it. My two tables are as such: One of the is a Contact list with phone numbers, names, and addresses. The other table is a paid history. The PhoneNumber field is how they're tied together. There are no duplicate entries in the Contact table but there are multiple paid instances per phone number in the other table.

My report groups them on the phone number, but I also need it to sort by date. My date field is marked as time/date, and it is in the paid table. The issue I'm running into is that I can either Group on PhoneNumber OR sort on the Date field but not both. When I set the Group as the top level, it ignores the Sort that I have set below it. If I take the sort and drag it up so that it becomes the top level, it won't group. When it doesn't group I'm left with multiple instances of the same Contact info... as in I get a new listing for every date that it has ever paid, whereas I need one a single Contact listing with each paid instance to be grouped underneath it.

Here's my query SQL:

```
SELECT 
    tblContributorsLead.FirstName, 
    tblContributorsLead.LastName, 
    tblContributorsLead.Address1, 
    tblContributorsLead.ZipCode, 
    tblContributorsLead.CityName, 
    tblPledgesLead.PledgeAmountRecd, 
    tblPledgesLead.DateRecd, 
    tblPledgesLead.PhoneNumber, 
    tblPledgesLead.DispositionTime, 
    tblPledgesLead.Agent, 
    tblPledgesLead.CampaignName, 
    tblPledgesLead.Custom20
FROM 
    tblContributorsLead 
    INNER JOIN 
    tblPledgesLead 
        ON tblContributorsLead.PhoneNumber = tblPledgesLead.PhoneNumber
WHERE 
    (((tblPledgesLead.PledgeAmountRecd)>0) 
        AND ((tblPledgesLead.DateRecd) Is Not Null));
```

Why would I only be able to either group OR sort but not both at the same time?

Edit: http://icloudbackups.com/stripped.zip is a copy of my database stripped down.

Comment: So you want all of the payment information for each Contact to appear together, but you want the Contacts themselves sorted by the date of their most recent payment. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. It needs to be in order based on their most recent payment.

Comment: There is no point sorting in the source query of the report. Reports do their own sorting.

Comment: I'm not doing any sorting in the query. I'm only filtering out results that I don't want. I don't want it to pull any records that haven't paid, nor ones without a received date. Both instances need to be covered because we purposefully have cases where we have a Contact without payment history, and we also have cases where we have a payment of "0" but it still has a date marked so we know the date in which they kicked out. I don't need either of those cases showing up.

Comment: As mentioned in the below replies, I've stripped down my database if that helps. http://icloudbackups.com/stripped.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand now what you wanted - to have the phone number groups with the most recent dates show up at the top. To do this you need to identify the Last (or First if you need it the other way around) `DateRecd` for each `PhoneNumber`.

```
SELECT SortingAndGrouping.LastDate, SortingAndGrouping.PhoneNumber, tblPledgesLead.DateRecd
FROM (tblContributorsLead INNER JOIN tblPledgesLead ON 
  tblContributorsLead.PhoneNumber = tblPledgesLead.PhoneNumber) INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT CDate(Format(tblPledgesLead.DateRecd,"MM/DD/YYYY")) As LastDate, tblPledgesLead.PhoneNumber
    FROM tblContributorsLead INNER JOIN tblPledgesLead ON
      tblContributorsLead.PhoneNumber = tblPledgesLead.PhoneNumber
    ORDER BY tblPledgesLead.DateRecd DESC)  AS SortingAndGrouping ON
  tblContributorsLead.PhoneNumber = SortingAndGrouping.PhoneNumber
ORDER BY SortingAndGrouping.LastDate DESC , SortingAndGrouping.PhoneNumber, tblPledgesLead.DateRecd DESC;
```

You will need to add the additional fields you want to display (I removed them here for clarity), and have the report enforce the same sorting I have here - Create a group for the LastDate column, then a group for the PhoneNumber column, then have the sorting specified.

Comment: Did that and it didn't change anything in the output.

Comment: You did that on the report itself? The report will override the settings in the source query.

Comment: Correct. Here I managed to strip down my database.

http://icloudbackups.com/stripped.zip

Comment: I think I got it now... you want to sort the groups by the first or last date in the details. I have revised my answer.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have any effect. I used your SQL there, re-added my fields back in, then on the report I made a group for phone number and a group for lastdate, then sorted by daterecd. There doesn't appear to be any change. Here's an updated version of my stripped down database: http://icloudbackups.com/stripped2.zip

Comment: The first group should be the lastDate. Don't include any header or footer, just tell it how to sort. Then put the group for phoneNumber. Last, add a sort for the dateRecd.

Comment: Ahhh I see. It had the LastDate being sorted by Quarter instead of Day by default. It looks good based on my stripped down database. Let me apply this to my main one, run my report fully, and I'll report back here in around an hour after it's all done.

Comment: Hrm. Now it's giving me a data type mismatch in expression error. Gonna play around with it a bit and see if I can figure out what it's talking about.

Comment: I have uploaded my version of the stripped DB you gave. The report and source query have been modified to group and sort as you want. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17098345/stripped.accdb

Comment: Like I said it works fine on my stripped DB. When I apply it to my main DB I get a data type mismatch error. I can make the error kind-of go away by removing the Sort for LastDate in the Query. However when I run the "fixed" Query it will again give me that same error in Report mode.

Comment: I see a lot of #Error's in the LastDate column when I remove all sorting options from your query. Something is definitely up with that and I'm not sure what would cause that. All dates are in Date/Time format. Why would that give a type mismatch?

Comment: Hmm. It seems that it is breaking on any instance of a record not having a DateRecd. We will always have records that are blank, i.e. people who are going to pay but haven't just yet. When I deleted all records from tblPledgesLead that didn't have a DateRecd set, all seems to be well. How can this be adjusted to account for those records without a DateRecd?

Comment: This will fix all the NULL values. Change the date from 9999 to 1900 if you want to make the Nulls show at the top instead of the bottom. CDate(Format(Nz([DateRecd],#1/1/9999#),"MM/DD/YYYY"))

Comment: WHERE DateRecd is not null

Comment: I've put that in a few different places but I'm still seeing the blanks as having a date of 1/1/9999. Where does that statement fit into the mix?

Comment: aha, it seems that by putting "<#1/1/9999#" inside the criteria for LastDate it omits them. That will do (unless you have a better way). Thank you very very much!

Comment: Hrm. So after going back and reviewing the results, it doesn't appear to be grouping properly still. I'm getting duplicate records showing up. What is happening is for each instance of a paid date, I'm getting another full record. I only need one instance of info from the tblContributorsLead and each instance from tblPledgesLead to be contained within that one single contributor lead. For reference, if you search the phone number 555-254-2995 you will find a copy of the entire lead with both paid instances on pages 41 and again on 742. The "copy" from 742 shouldn't be appearing.

Comment: Hey I went ahead and marked this as solved and made a new question since it's now onto a different issue.. Thank you very much!